# jQuery Mobile "Persistent Footer Navbar" buttons don't work until after refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile

### Environment

- jQuery 1.7.1
- jQuery Mobile 1.0 Final
- PHP w/ CodeIgniter 2.1.0
- LAMP
- Testing on:

  - GSM iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1
  - Kubuntu 11.10

    - Google Chrome 17.0.963.12 dev
    - Firefox 9.0.1

### Problem

On loading the page, jQuery Mobile appropriately assumes that I want to view the first "page wrapper" and display that quite beautifully.  **However, when clicking the "Usage" link, nothing happens.**  By nothing, I mean that clicking it does not load the page with the appropriate ID, nor does it do a post-back/ajax call.  However, **if I refresh the page, I can then use the menu** (including the Usage button and then the Transaction button while on the usage page) as it should work.

I have looked at the Chrome Developer Tools Network tab and nothing shows up (as it shouldn't because it's an anchor link and the content is already in the DOM).  I have tested this on my iPhone and Chrome/Firefox (relevant version numbers above).

I'd really like to have these two pages on the same DOM but I suspect that splitting them up would work.  I'd like to leave that as a last resort.

### Question

Do I have some syntax error or am I possibly missing something key to the jQuery Mobile environment?

### Code

**Note:** The page below is wrapped in a normal HTML>Head+Body skeletal structure, base_view, I have omitted that but if you would like to see it, just ask and I will append it.  The only additions are a meta tag for viewport config, two Javascript script tags and two CSS link tags.

The link that points to the following page/DOM:

```
<a href="account_detail.php" data-role="button">Account Details</a>
```

The page with the persistent navbar:

```
<!-- ============ PAGE ONE ============ -->
<div id="transactions" data-role="page" class="ui-page"> 
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="home.php" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-button-left" data-direction="reverse" data-prefetch>Back</a>
    <h1>Transactions</h1>
</div> <!-- /header -->

<div id="content" data-role="content" class="ui-content">
    Hello World!
</div> <!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="account_details">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Transactions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#usage" data-transition="fade" data-prefetch>Usage</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- /navbar -->
</div> <!-- /footer -->
</div> <!-- /page one -->

<!-- ============ PAGE TWO ============ -->
<div id="usage" data-role="page" class="ui-page">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="home.php" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-button-left" data-direction="reverse" data-prefetch>Back</a>
    <h1>Usage</h1>
</div> <!-- /header -->

<div id="content" data-role="content" class="ui-content">
    Hello World, Again!
</div> <!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="account_details">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#transactions" data-transition="fade" data-prefetch>Transactions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Usage</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- /navbar -->
</div> <!-- /footer -->
```

### Thanks

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this and for any help/feedback you can provide!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sigh.  I just didn't read the documentation properly.  When linking to a page with multiple pages (multiple data-role="page" divs, or "page wrappers"), the rel="external" param has to be set on the link that points to the multi-page document.

So the solution was to change:

`<a href="account_detail.php" data-role="button">Account Details</a>`

To:

`<a href="account_detail.php" data-role="button" rel="external">Account Details</a>`

Comment: Hey dude you helped me :) Mark that sucker as 'answered'.

Comment: @gyaresu Haha glad to hear it.  Thanks for reminding me to mark that as answered.  I always forget to do that after the 2 day waiting period is up.